# Preventing expansion/evaluation of parameter in ssh command

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have a shell script that runs a docker container on a remote server.

I'm trying to send the hostname of the remote server into the container but i just get the hostname of my local computer where i run the script.

The command looks like this in the script:

```
ssh $remote "docker run -h '`hostname`' \
                        -e 'VARIABLE=$SCRIPT_VAR' \
                        -e 'HOST_HOSTNAME=`hostname`' \
                        ..."
```

Both hostname and the environment variable host.hostname becomes the name of my local computer.

I know I can use singlequotes like this:

```
ssh $remote 'echo "`hostname`"'
```

and it will work. But then i cannot use scriptvariables like the `$SCRIPT_VAR`

How can i get it to evaluate on the remote server instead while also being able to use variables?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know the difference. I just want something in between. Think i figured it out myself though.

Comment: Your "solution" leaves `$SCRIPT_VAR` unquoted, which may break your command if it contains whitespace.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to ensure that the expansion of `$SCRIPT_VAR` is quoted to prevent it from being subjected to word splitting or pathname expansion.

```
ssh $remote 'docker run -h "$(hostname)" \
                        -e "VARIABLE='"$SCRIPT_VAR"'" \
                        -e "HOST_HOSTNAME=$(hostname)" \
                        ...'
```